# How do you tie your shoes one handed?

Tags: gear, knots, footwear

My arm is currently in a sling with a separated shoulder from a mountain bike accident, so I'm trying to learn how to do everyday tasks one handed. Shoelaces are proving annoyingly difficult. What's a good one handed shoelace knot?

**Note:** I'm not interested in recommendations for wearing different types of laceless shoes. I'm only interested in answers that provide details on how to tie one-handed knots in lace-up shoes, preferably without having to re-lace the shoe.

Comment: by using velcro shoes

Comment: @amphibient You don't tie knotsth in velcro sthilly... But seriously, I want to learn some new knots. I don't have any velcro shoes.

Comment: This looks neat: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhmeN5w4sKg

Comment: A coworker of mine swears by this no knot style of laces for all his walking shoes / hiking boots. They're called lock laces which basically means you never tie your shoes. I'd say in the event of long term injury these are probably better than one handed tying or velcro, as you can lace them into your current boots :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its nothing to do with outdoors

Comment: @mattnz Tell that to [Aron Ralston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aron_Ralston).

Answer (score 17):

First, I'm sorry to hear about your arm. Tying a shoelace with one hand may almost be impossible but you could follow these simple steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
                                            <sup>[(Source of above diagrams)](http://www.theoatc.org/resources/documents/onehanded_shoe_tie.pdf)</sup>

---

If all else fails use velcro shoes:

[image]

Comment: Excellent visuals. I didn't even bother to read it.

Comment: This works well for only one shoe, on the shoe opposite of your good arm, it gets kinda awkward.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is not the answer you are looking for, but it deserves to be mentioned. As @amphibient mentions in a comment.

People with long term medical issues that make tying shoes difficult, generally use shoes with Velcro straps or shoes that slip on without laces or ties.

Alternatively, for short term issue, you can use the shoes you have now, and tie them loosely (*put them in your lap where you can use two hands*).  A loosely tied pair of soft shoes will slip on and off without difficulty.

Hard dress shoes (for the office) are not going to work well with the loosely tied option.

Answer (score 4):

For a one-handed knot that doesn't require relacing, try the [one-handed variant of the "Ian Knot"](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/ianknotvideo.htm#onehanded) from [Ian's shoelace site](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/index.htm). The result is identical to a standard shoelace knot, though I suspect it will take some practice to master.

A more straightforward option is the ["one handed shoelace knot"](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/onehandedknot.htm)  Unfortunately this one does require relacing, but allows for a very simple one-handed knot once the lace is set up. The idea is that you "anchor" one end of the lace permanently, letting you tie off the other end by looping it back on itself. A diagram is probably more useful than my attempted explanation:

[image: one-handed knot]

<sup>[Source: www.fieggen.com](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/onehandedknot.htm)</sup>

The linked page has step-by-step instructions with diagrams, details, and a photograph of the knot in use.

If you have a lot of eyelets and don't mind a slightly loose fit, there is also a [one-handed lacing](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/onehandedlacing.htm) which relies on eyelet friction alone to keep the lace tight -- you just tuck in the loose end of the shoelace rather than tying it off.

(I found the link to the anchored one-handed knot in an answer by [Rajath](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/12042/rajath), which was swiftly deleted for being a link-only answer. However, it seemed to me to be the best suggestion posted so far, so I thought it worth salvaging.)

Comment: For any question to do with shoe laces and knots, the Ian Fieggen site is the first you should check out.